# Accessing mysql through URL

Tags: mysql, security

Can I Use My Browser to Access MySQL server by sending requests in URL?

I have Tried giving URL of my Server and port to which it is bound send the user name and password in URL as properties and value

```
http://127.0.0.1:3306/?user=root&password=password
```

But it gives error like (J���
5.5.28����/,-<&Hv;�ÿ÷�€����������ca>OR08fzTsi�mysql_native_password�!��ÿ„#08S01Got packets out of order)

Does using Any protocol Work?

Comment: What are you expecting after a successful login? See some dashboard of some sort?

Answer (score 3):

You are attempting to access a server bound on a port that does not speak the protocol of http, but the socket open request is naturally granted.

Mysql responds in non-http and non-html output, and your browser displays the gobbly-gook. As your browser is naturally not a mysql client with baked in mysql library calls to deal with that handshake, the train just went off the tracks.

Instead of trying to craft an extension to mysql to perform this, it is best to redirect one's focus to the likes of PHP, asp.net, a java back-end middle-ware, etc.

---

As for passing values like you are in the URL, I suggest you read [This Blog Here](http://www.troyhunt.com/2015/10/breaches-traders-plain-text-passwords.html) and jump down to the text showing:

> Doesn’t look too bad? Let’s take a look at the URL:
>
> A_URL?domain=&subdomain=sdjflsdhkfhds&name=asdasdf&email=aaaaa@letthemeatspam.com&pass1=ThisIsMyPassword&pass2=ThisIsMyPassword&aggree=yes&error_multiple=&error_domain=&error_subdomain=&error_name=&error_email=&error_pass=2&error_tos=&error_number=&error_js=&error_disposable=1&error_bad_gmail=

Not only is that information sitting in your users cache, it is visible along the way between the user and server (perhaps half a dozen hops) and is logged. **If that doesn't raise an eyebrow of concern**, I don't know what more to say.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use your browser to access MySQL without installing a browser-based tool such as [phpMyAdmin](https://www.phpmyadmin.net). I do not recommend this.

Instead, just use the [MySQL command line client](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql.html). From a shell prompt:

```
mysql -h127.0.0.1 -uroot -p
```

You will be prompted for your password.